# cs50 speller problem hash table doesn't seem to form in load function

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, cs50

currently doing the speller problem of cs50 pset5.

I'm having a trouble with forming the hash table and i think it causes a segmentation fault later on when i try to run a function that searches the table.

this is the function that creates the hash table:

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");  //opens dictionary file
    if (dict == NULL) // if cant be opened loading failed
    {
        return false;
    }


    char w[LENGTH + 1]; //buffer (length is the maximum character number
    int i = 0; //index within word
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", w) != EOF) // scanning the dictionary for words
    {
        int x = hash(w); //getting the number of the linked list within the table
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node)); //allocating memory for a new node
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(w) + 1; j++) // documenting the word within the new node
        {
            n->word[i] = w[j];
        }

        n->next = table[x];
        table[x] = n; //new node is the beginning of the linked list

        dicsize++;
    }

    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}
```

my main question is whether my code for forming the table is correct and if not then why
thank you in advance
and this is the entire code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

int dicsize = 0;
// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int x = hash(word);
    node *cur = table[x];

    while(table[x] != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(word, cur->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(cur == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    char temp = tolower(word[0]);
    int place = (temp - 97);
    return place;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");  //opens dictionary file
    if (dict == NULL) // if cant be opened loading failed
    {
        return false;
    }


    char w[LENGTH + 1]; //buffer
    int i = 0; //index within word
    while(fscanf(dict, "%s", w) != EOF) // scanning the dictionary for words
    {
        int x = hash(w); //getting the number of the linked list within the table
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node)); //allocating memory for a new node
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(w) + 1; j++) // documenting the word within the new node
        {
            n->word[i] = w[j];
        }

        n->next = table[x];
        table[x] = n; //new node is the beginning of the linked list

        dicsize++;
    }

fclose(dict);
return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    printf("%i", dicsize);
    return dicsize;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The only thing that immediately jumps out is the failure to validate the length of `word < LENGTH` in `check()` and failure to protect your array bounds and failure to check for empty string in your call to `fscanf()`.  Which is better as `fgets()`, but if using `fscanf()` should be `fscanf(dict, "%44s", w) != 1` (if `LENGTH` is defined as `45`). The entire `for (int j = 0; j < strlen(w) + 1; j++)` loop should be replaced with `strcpy (n->word[i], w);`

Comment: Also, a hash table ***load factor*** (e.g. `buckets_used / total_buckets`) should never exceed `0.7`. With `const unsigned int N = 26;` and some of the texts (e.g. the `holmes.txt`) containing `1137706` words -- you are really building more of a linked list with chained buckets than a hash table. Assuming a minimal 1M stack, you may want to maximize `N = 13100`. (while not keeping the recommended load factor it will dramatically reduce the number of collisions and chained buckets you have.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < strlen(w) + 1; j++) n->word[i] = w[j];` there should be no `i` in this, that should have been a `j`. As `i` is not changing in the loop, you are dumping all characters in one spot and also not terminating the string.

Comment: @dratenik bingo! Post that as the answer. That's what I was looking for but didn't snap too. Also in my comment above, that would replace the loop with `strcpy (n->word, w);`

Comment: yep i changed it to strcpy and added the validation that David suggested and it works great now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The likely culprit is

```
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(w) + 1; j++) // documenting the word within the new node
{
    n->word[i] = w[j];
}
```

As `i` is not changing inside the loop, instead of copying the string it will dump all the chars into one. The other index should also be `j`. (as in `n->word[j] = w[j];`)

It would be better to do this as `strcpy` anyway.